# Building a navigation in asp.net using treeview control

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

I'm trying to build a windows explorer like simple navigation menu in asp.net using a Treeview control 
And I have placed a Listview control which displays the children of the selected node dynamically.

```
Root    
  -Group01
    -subgroup1    
      -1.1    
      -1.2   
    -subgroup2    
      -1.1
-Group02
```

On pageload I have fixed the Treenode to 0 so Group01 and Group02 buttons are inserted in the Listview.

What I want to know is suppose I click on the Group01 button in the Listview it should display 
subgroup1 and subgroup1 and so on instead of the rootnode's children.

This is the .aspx code

```
<div>
<asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server" OnSelectedNodeChanged="TreeView1_SelectedNodeChanged">
    <Nodes>
        <asp:TreeNode SelectAction="SelectExpand" Text="root" Value="root">
            <asp:TreeNode Expanded="False" SelectAction="SelectExpand" Text="group01" Value="group01">
                <asp:TreeNode Text="subgroup1" Value="subgroup1">
                    <asp:TreeNode Text="1.1" Value="1.1"></asp:TreeNode>
                    <asp:TreeNode Text="1.2" Value="1.2"></asp:TreeNode>
                </asp:TreeNode>
                <asp:TreeNode Text="subgroup2" Value="subgroup2">
                    <asp:TreeNode Text="1.1" Value="1.1"></asp:TreeNode>
                </asp:TreeNode>
            </asp:TreeNode>
            <asp:TreeNode Expanded="False" SelectAction="SelectExpand" Text="group02" Value="group02">
            </asp:TreeNode>
       </asp:TreeNode>
    </Nodes>
</asp:TreeView>
</div>
 <div>
    <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server">
    </asp:ListView>
</div>
```

aspx.cs code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TreeView1.Nodes[0].Select();
    TreeView1_SelectedNodeChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
protected void TreeView1_SelectedNodeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ListView1.Controls.Clear();
    List<string> childs = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < TreeView1.SelectedNode.ChildNodes.Count; i++)
    {
        childs.Add(TreeView1.SelectedNode.ChildNodes[i].Text);
    }
    foreach (string val in childs)
    {
        Button btn = new Button
        {
            Text = val
        };
        ListView1.Controls.Add(btn);
        ListView1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</br></br>"));
     }
}
```

Since I'm new to this I want to know whether this is the right way to do it or some alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

First, your .aspx  file didn't contain the ListView1.

Second, "subgroup1 and subgroup1" may be is a semantic error.

I think you difined a Listview and the ListViewItem mapping the treeNode. You want click the ListViewItem to control the treenode expand or collapse。

Or you want to click the "text" of node to control instead of the "+"/"-" symbol.

In any case, So you must find the node, and judge Expanded.

May be this code is help you.

```
    protected void TreeView1_SelectedNodeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TreeView tree = (TreeView)sender;
        TreeNode node = tree.SelectedNode;
        bool isExpanded = Boolean.Parse(node.Expanded.ToString());
        if (isExpanded)
            node.Collapse();
        else
            node.Expand();
        tree.SelectedNode.Selected = false;
    }
```

Comment: Sorry about that missing code in .aspx. Yes I want to control the "+"/"-" action by clicking the Listviewitem.